# Unable to set the ancestors: com.businessobjects.report.web.json.JSONException

Tags: java, json, logging, crystal-reports

I am getting below error message from webreporting.jar which is crystal report jar. Could someone help me to find why i am getting this error.

> 11:47:59,828 ERROR
>   [com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Unable to set the ancestors:
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.json.JSONException:
>   JSONObject["ancestors"] is not a JSONArray.   at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:456)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter.getDiscreteValueFromJSON(JSONParameter.java:708)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter.getValueFromJSON(JSONParameter.java:635)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter.jsonToFieldValues(JSONParameter.java:592)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter.getValues(JSONParameter.java:455)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.JSONParameter.toParameterField(JSONParameter.java:919)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.shared.ParametersHelper.jsonToFields(ParametersHelper.java:326)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.state.ViewerState.restoreCommonState(ViewerState.java:2872)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.state.ViewerState.restore(ViewerState.java:2775)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.component.ViewerContainer.restoreState(ViewerContainer.java:211)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.WorkflowController.loadViewState(WorkflowController.java:418)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.WorkflowController.init(WorkflowController.java:393)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.WorkflowController.doLifecycle(WorkflowController.java:252)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.businessobjects.report.web.WorkflowController.doAsyncLifecycle(WorkflowController.java:106)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerUpdater._processHttpRequest(CrystalReportViewerUpdater.java:61)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.processHttpRequest(ServerControl.java:345)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet.doUpdate(CrystalReportViewerServlet.java:206)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet.doPost(CrystalReportViewerServlet.java:194)
>   [webreporting.jar:14.1.2.1171]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_76] I read somewhere that add below line in log4j and
>   place them into WEB-INF/classes folder which will solve the problem.
>   however it is not working for me. I am new in crystal report.

Comment: I have used this setting as suggested on some page <logger name="com.businessobjects.report.web">
    <level value="FATAL"/>
  </logger>

Comment: Could someone help me on it to get it resolve.